# Http client program using socket not working

Tags: c, http, sockets, network-programming, httpclient

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>


/* getLine() Reads a line from a stream and stores it in "string"


 size_t getLine(char **string, FILE *stream)
 {
 size_t rd=0;
 char s;
 int ln = getline(string,&rd,stream);

 if(ln == -1)
 {

 return -1;
 }
 return rd;
 }


 /* Convert file descriptor into stream (i.e., FILE*).  Exit if there is a
 * failure. */

FILE* getStream(int sock)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fdopen(sock,"a+b");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"error opening socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return fp;
}

/* Creates a TCP socket and returns the file descriptor for it. */

int createSocket(char *hostname, char *port)
{
    if(hostname == NULL || port == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "One or more parameters passed to createSocket() are NULL\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Request a TCP connection using the version of IP that is configured
     on the machine.
     */

    struct addrinfo * result, *h;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE|AI_ADDRCONFIG;

    int error = getaddrinfo(hostname, "http", &hints, &result);

    if(error != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\n error in getaddrinfo:%s\n",gai_strerror(error));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* TODO: Create a socket using socket() and the "result" structure.
     Check for an error. If one occurs, print a message and exit.
     */


    for(h=result; h != NULL; h = h->ai_next)
    {
        int sock = socket(h->ai_family, h->ai_socktype, h->ai_protocol);

        if(sock == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"\nerror in creating Socket");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }



        /* TODO: Call connect() with "sock" and information from the
         "result" struct to start a TCP connection. Check for error. If
         one occurs, print message and exit.
         */

        if(connect(sock, h->ai_addr, h->ai_addrlen) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"\nerror in connecting");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        freeaddrinfo(result);
        return sock;

    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    /* TODO: Check number of arguments */

    if(argc<2)
    {
        printf("expected a name for resolving");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Setup socket. */

    int sock = createSocket(argv[1], argv[2]);
    FILE *stream = getStream(sock);
    printf("\n###### CLIENT IS SENDING THE FOLLOWING TO THE SERVER\n");


    /* TODO: Write HTTP request to "stream" */

    printf(" GET / HTTP/1.0\n Host: %s\n Connection: close \r\n \r\n", argv[1]);
    fprintf(stream, "GET / HTTP/1.0\n Host: %s\n Connection: close \r\n \r\n", argv[1]);

    while(1) // while there is data to read
    {
        char *string = NULL;
        printf("#####CLIENT RECEIVED THE FOLLOWING FROM SERVER\n");
        int len = getLine(&string, stream);
        printf("%s",string);
        while((len=getLine(&string, stream)) != -1)
        {
            printf("%s",string);
        }


        fclose(stream);
        printf("\n##### Connection closed by server\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        free(string);

    } // end infinite loop
}
```

Comment: And the question is... what? Find your bug?

Comment: I dont know what is wrong with my code especially When I give request as GET /HTTP/1.0  it getting a response from server but when I give GET / HTTP/1.0 its not getting any response please help

Comment: Shouldn't *all* lines sent be terminated by a `\r\n`?

Comment: For next time: Please don't post full programs as this is not fun to scroll through and look for the relevant lines. Try to identify the relevant lines yourself and only post these (like sending the request line in this example as connecting and receiving is obviously working). Try to phrase a question in your top posting explaining the stuff you did not post and don't let others guess what you might be asking. If you have additions to the original post try to edit the post and add this information there so everyone can see it without scrolling through the comments.

Answer (score 3):

You are not respecting the [HTTP protocol specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html).  It clearly requires you to terminate every line in the request header using CRLF, which means \r\n. In your case you are terminating some lines only with LF so the behavior of the server is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use curl library to construct http(s) request.
have look at this

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/